# Sticky header with variable height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I need to have a header that's always displayed at the top of the viewport, even when the user scrolls down. That bit is fairly easy, using something like this:

```
body {
    padding-top: 100px; /* height of the header */
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -500px; /* Half the width of the header */
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

However, now my problem is that **I don't always know how tall the header will be**, because the client wants a top banner ad to also follow along, but that might not always be there.

So, sometimes the header might look like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="#" class="top_banner" />
    <div id="headerbar">
        <h1>Site logo</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

And sometimes it might look like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="headerbar">
        <h1>Site logo</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

The good news is that the banner ad will always have the same dimensions. So basically #header could be 100px without the banner, and 250px if the banner is there.

My question to you is: is there a nice CSS ways to solve this? If not, how could I solve it using Javascript?

Comment: have you tried `min-height` & `max-height` instead of using a fixed `height` for `#header`

Comment: @Ahsan Rathod That's not the issue. That was just an example. In reality, the header width is fluid (it's just that it doesn't change much, so in practice it's one of two sizes). The issue was that I didn't know how tall the header would be, so the top padding on body would be incorrect and had to be updated using Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('body').css('padding-top', $('#header').height() + 'px');
});
```

this can help you

Answer (score 1):

(Lazy answer)

Change the className of the `#header` div depending on whether it has an image or not.

CSS

```
body {
    padding-top: 100px; /* height of the header */
}

.header_no_image, .header_with_image {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -500px; /* Half the width of the header */
    width: 1000px;
}

.header_no_image {
  height: 100px;
}
.header_with_image {
  height: 250px;
}
```

With image

```
<div id="header" class="header_with_image">
    <img src="#" class="top_banner" />
    <div id="headerbar">
        <h1>Site logo</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Without image

```
<div id="header" class="header_no_image">
    <div id="headerbar">
        <h1>Site logo</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is probably a better solution but this would work...

Comment: That is indeed hacky, but I like the creative thinking. I will give you an upvote, because it would work. But I think I'll go with one of the other solutions, as they're more future-safe (in case they some day decide to roll out a different sized ad, or change the margins somehow).

Comment: what if there is a third option, so it would be messy after, case for that case for that and case for that and who knows what else, probably banner wont have same height always...

Comment: I know, I did say this wasn't perfect (or even good), but it does fulfill the OP's requirements...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about CSS, but this javascript should do the basic job for you:

```
document.body.style.paddingTop = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a jquery plugin to encounter this kind of problem: https://github.com/ArthurClemens/jquery-sticky-plugin

Check if this works for you.